# efficiently acquiring a screenshot of the windows desktop

Tags: c++, windows, performance, bitmap, gdi

Is there a more efficient way of getting a copy of the windows desktop ( using GDI or any other library ) than the code below

```
HDC      dcDesktop;
HDC         dcMem;
HBITMAP     hbmpMem;
HBITMAP     hOriginal;
BITMAP      bmpDesktopCopy;

dcDesktop   = GetDC( GetDesktopWindow() ); 
dcMem       = CreateCompatibleDC( dcDesktop );
hbmpMem     = CreateCompatibleBitmap( dcMem, m_lWidth, m_lHeight );

BitBlt( dcMem, 0, 0, m_lWidth, m_lHeight, dcDesktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

// Copy the hbmpMem to the desktop copy
GetObject(hbmpMem, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bmpDesktopCopy);
```

Comment: That looks pretty efficient to me. What's your criteria to measure "efficiency"?

Comment: What performance problems are you having with this?

Comment: If you need to repeatedly acquire screenshots I think you may get more efficient using DirectX.

Comment: Can you provide an example using DirectX?

Comment: Does this actually work? My experience has been you need to call `CreateCompatibleBitmap` with `dcDesktop`, not `dcMem`. Plus you're missing a call to `SelectObject` to select the bitmap into the DC.

Comment: As far as I remember it worked fine, it was just slow.  I'd long since gone with a DirectX solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx

This page has a couple different ways to take screenshots. The DirectX method they use seems simple enough.

Aside from what's mentioned in that article, I don't think there's any more an efficient method of capturing the desktop.