# How to capture part of the screen and save it to a BMP?

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make screen screenshot with win32 in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c)

I am currently trying to create an application that saved a portion of the screen to a bmp. I have found [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx) but I really don't know what to do with it. I have tried searching for some answers but I still haven't found a clarifying one using C++.

So, basically I want this function:

```
bool capturePartScreen(int x, int y, int w int, h, string dest){
    //Capture part of screen according to coordinates, width and height.
    //Save that captured image as a bmp to dest.
    //Return true if success, false if failure
}
```

BitBlt:

```
BOOL BitBlt(
    __in  HDC hdcDest,
    __in  int nXDest,
    __in  int nYDest,
    //The three above are the ones I don't understand!
    __in  int nWidth,
    __in  int nHeight,
    __in  HDC hdcSrc,
    __in  int nXSrc,
    __in  int nYSrc,
    __in  DWORD dwRop
);
```

What should that hdc be and how do I obtain the bmp?

Comment: Look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c).

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292700/efficiently-acquiring-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-desktop), it should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Jesse: Thanks, that post helped me out quite a bit :)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, since a key part of the question is how to get the bitmap into a file.  The other question does not address that at all.

Comment: Indeed.. Well, at least I managed to post an answer before it was closed :/

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all - aside from the file saving, this question asks about capturing *part* of a screen whereas the linked question asks about capturing the *entire* screen. Trigger-happy question closing is annoying.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It took a while, but I have now finally ended up with a functioning script.

Requirements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <olectl.h>
```

Also you might(?) have to add ole32, oleaut32 and uuid to your linker.

screenCapturePart:

```
bool screenCapturePart(int x, int y, int w, int h, LPCSTR fname){
    HDC hdcSource = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSource);

    int capX = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, HORZRES);
    int capY = GetDeviceCaps(hdcSource, VERTRES);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSource, w, h);
    HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, w, h, hdcSource, x, y, SRCCOPY);
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMemory, hBitmapOld);

    DeleteDC(hdcSource);
    DeleteDC(hdcMemory);

    HPALETTE hpal = NULL;
    if(saveBitmap(fname, hBitmap, hpal)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

saveBitmap:

```
bool saveBitmap(LPCSTR filename, HBITMAP bmp, HPALETTE pal)
{
    bool result = false;
    PICTDESC pd;

    pd.cbSizeofstruct   = sizeof(PICTDESC);
    pd.picType      = PICTYPE_BITMAP;
    pd.bmp.hbitmap  = bmp;
    pd.bmp.hpal     = pal;

    LPPICTURE picture;
    HRESULT res = OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pd, IID_IPicture, false,
                       reinterpret_cast<void**>(&picture));

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res))
    return false;

    LPSTREAM stream;
    res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, &stream);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res))
    {
    picture->Release();
    return false;
    }

    LONG bytes_streamed;
    res = picture->SaveAsFile(stream, true, &bytes_streamed);

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0,
                 CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(res) || !file)
    {
    stream->Release();
    picture->Release();
    return false;
    }

    HGLOBAL mem = 0;
    GetHGlobalFromStream(stream, &mem);
    LPVOID data = GlobalLock(mem);

    DWORD bytes_written;

    result   = !!WriteFile(file, data, bytes_streamed, &bytes_written, 0);
    result  &= (bytes_written == static_cast<DWORD>(bytes_streamed));

    GlobalUnlock(mem);
    CloseHandle(file);

    stream->Release();
    picture->Release();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: For those getting E_UNEXPECTED after OleCreatePictureIndirect, I forgot to set PICTDESC.picType to PICTYPE_BMP.

Comment: Just a note for future readers... In that first code block `screenCapturePart` the bit that reads `BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, w, h, hdcSource, x, x, SRCCOPY);` should actually be `BitBlt(hdcMemory, 0, 0, w, h, hdcSource, x, y, SRCCOPY);`.

Comment: @ChrisBarlow Fixed, thanks for noticing and telling!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I SO did not want to figure that out for myself. One note, I was getting `cannot convert argument from 'LPCSTR' to 'LPCWSTR'` which I fixed by using `CreateFileA` instead of `CreateFile`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GetDC(NULL)` to get the device context for the entire screen, then use that with `BitBlt` as the source device context.

As for the rest of what to do:

[Bitmap Creation (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Bitmap Storage (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know, but what I don't understand is how to define the destination hdc. How do I go from a hdc to a bmp? Sorry for not clarifying that.