# Combine bitmaps - GDI/GDI+?

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I want to know if its possible for example to enumerate all desktop visible windows to create bitmap of them and to combine all bitmaps into one so you get FULL screenshot of the desktop ?

Most likely using GDI/GD+ but any external libs are also welcome.
Preferable language C\C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any more information how to do it ? Sorry if i asked the wrong way for help...

Comment: Please see the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292700/efficiently-acquiring-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-desktop

Comment: Hans, i know about this, i want to do it the way i ask for, someone can just tell me or give me example how to combine such bitmaps ?

Comment: @VisaToHell just pass a big enough size to `CreateCompatibleBitmap` and then do multiple `BitBlt`s with the correct offsets and done.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie, you show me example where this is used ?

Comment: @VisaToHell it's self-explanatory.

Comment: Something came in my head.... what will happen when one window is over other, i mean partially they will share same location, will that cause errors or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For copying between bitmaps in GDI, take a look at [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).