# Create AeroGlass effect in windows 8

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, aero-glass

I want create AeroGlass effect in my application (not whole system) but it seem Microsoft was drop this feature from windows 8, so, I have to create it my own.

To create this effect, I'm going to get a rectangle of image below the window of my application and apply gauss blur on it and finaly draw to my windows. But how can I get image below the windows?

Comment: This post may be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5292700/2065121

Comment: @RogerRowland: Thanks you for reply, but it seem all the methods capture whole screen (including window itself), so it can't help me to create glasseffect :-(

Comment: The point of leaving the non-client area rendering up to Windows is that your app will look up to date, even though you didn't change any code.  Maybe the glass effect still looks "cool" to you but your customers will be less than impressed.  Especially five years from now, you'll look like an old tired and unmaintained app by then.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks you for your reply, I do this stuff only just for fun only, I wonder how AeroGlass effect was implemented and trying to re-implement a simple version :D